# Lancaster Or Porter

Tags: python, nltk, stemming, porter-stemmer

Which of `lancaster` or `porter` is best for Stemming ?
Is Porter `stemmer` too old for stemming?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that questions like "What is the best X" are usually frowned upon. You may also want to add more detail to your question (e.g. what you tried, what worked, what didn't, etc.).

Comment: Sorry . i do these since

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porter is simple, but if you are stemming huge amounts of data, it's not a bad option.

Comment: Thanks. But i found the porter stemmer for 1970 and is too old and i say that not suitable for stemming.

Comment: Well, quicksort has been around since 1960 and its still considered one of the fastest sorting algorithms ;) It often just depends on what you want to stem/sort/etc.

Comment: i want to stem 400000 text of news site and found most collocation in this site